# Android - HTML Geolocation

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation

I'm having trouble of using the geolocation on my website on android phones.

I've got the following javascript code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log("true"); //gets logged
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sucess, error, {timeout: 5000});
}
```

It always times out with error.code 3 and error.message "Timeout expired".

This happens on version 2.x and 4.x of Android.

Please keep in mind that this is NOT in combination with phonegap or similar. It's a plain old website that's opened in a browser.

The code works fine on iPhones.

Is there sth. wrong with my code or is it a problem on the android side?

Comment: may be 5 seconds is not enough

Comment: is 'Enable Location' checked in your browser settings ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below code on my android without issues. If you want to call the function again just set a timeout in the coordinates function.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log("true"); //gets logged
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(coordinates);
} 

function coordinates(location) {
    latitude =  location.coords.latitude;
    longitude = location.coords.longitude;
}
```